# How to change runtime used by `mvn` cmd in Win 10?

Tags: java, maven

How to change the runtime used by `mvn` in Win10 from jre to jdk ?

[image: changing mvn's runtime]

Right now it is pointing to JRE which needs to be changed to JDK. Where to change this?

This in-turn is causing errors while running `mvn` cmds inside projects:

[image: mvn using jre instead of jdk]

Where are the appropriate settings to be set?

Comment: The usual: Java/jre home and path

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: @Marged thanks. I have been helping someone else with this and asked on their behalf. was assured the variables are set properly and I searched too for other reasons for some time. Thought could be a different issue other than incorrect path

Answer (score 2):

Change you environment variable and add a variable called JAVA_HOME with the path to you're jdk's *folder, then add the bin folder to your PATH variable too

Comment: Variable Name : JAVA_HOME
Variable Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

Variable Name : PATH 
Variable Value : %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: I usually do this in a batch file. This allows for multiple versions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set JAVA_HOME to the JDK folder (where `javac.exe` is, minus `bin`) and probably add it in the PATH (see below).

Under Windows, however, if you use environment variable using the GUI, you will have to restart your cmd.exe for this to apply.

You can also do that:

```
set JAVA_HOME=E:\apps\portable\java\openjdk-11.0.5+10-hotspot 
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Which will apply in the cmd where you execute it.

And try running:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" -version
```

Or (if PATH was modified):

```
javac -version
```

If that fail, then the path is invalid.

Comment: `java.exe`exists in both JRE and JDK, it is about the `javac.exe`

Comment: @robert maven picks up javac from this

Comment: In this case, most important check that must work: `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" -version`. If not, the `JAVA_HOME` points to the wrong directory.